# REST API url for returning a subset of object for dropdown list

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

In my system users can create an Account entity using the endpoint `/api/account/`. Using this endpoint they can add/edit the object which has quite a number of properties.

There is another entity (Service) which when creating it in the UI they have to specify what Account to use.

I don't want them to retrieve all the Accounts and their data as per the `/api/account/` endpoint as there is extra information that is not required, all that is needed is an ID and a Name.

I could accept a query string parameter which specifies what fields to return but the fields will always be the same so don't want to have to do this for every endpoint, I'd rather make a generic endpoint for all entities.

So what RESTful options do I have for returning a (consistent) subset of data? Could I do something like `/api/relatable/{entity}`?

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can break your entities up so the account entity is the bare essentials and then have an accountDetails entity that has everything else. This would keep your entity small and avoid the need to creating a subset of data all together. Your route could be /api/accounts/{id} to get the basic account and then /api/account/{id}/details to get all the rest of the properties. The database would be a 1:1 relationship.

Another option is to use OData $select syntax. See the [specs here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398163). I have been moving away from OData myself because I feel it exposes too much and too much knowledge of the underlying scheme is needed, however, there are some nice things about it and this should solve your problem.